# How to extend Generic abstract Class with <E extends Comparable<E>>

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree, abstract-class

I'm trying to make an abstract class `AbstractBinSearchTree` like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractBinSearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>>
{ 
   public abstract void add(E element);
   public abstract void add(Collection<E> elemente);

   public List<E> retrieveInOrder(Pos<E> p) {
   ...
   }
```

My question is now how to extend from this class. I want to make an `ArrayBinTreeSearch` which I can instantiate like this:

```
AbstractBinSearchTree<Elem> tree = new ArrayBinSearchTree<Elem>();
```

I tried this:

```
public class ArrayBinSearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends AbstractBinSearchTree<Comparable<E>>{

Comparable<E>[] _tree;

public ArrayBinSearchTree(int size)
{
    _tree = new Comparable[size];
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void add(Comparable<?> element) {
    ...
}
```

But I doesn't really feel like this is the correct way to use it. Also I cannot instantiate like I mentioned above.

Comment: I think you should have had `extends AbstractBinSearchTree<E>`, not `extends AbstractBinSearchTree<Comparable<E>>`

Comment: Yes `Elem` implements `Comparable<Elem>`

Comment: This does not work. I get a bound mismatch. I think because `E` is not bound to `Comparable` @khelwood

Comment: Your code keeps saying that `E` must be comparable. If you're trying to use it on a type that is not comparable, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to replace the following line:

```
public class ArrayBinSearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends AbstractBinSearchTree<Comparable<E>>{
```

With:

```
public class ArrayBinSearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends AbstractBinSearchTree<E>{
```

Otherwise you'll restrict the parameters of any methods in `AbstractBinSearchTree`. In addition, expand the generic type of `AbstractBinSearchTree` as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractBinSearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
```

Also, your ArrayBinSearchTree constructor has an `int` parameter:

```
AbstractBinSearchTree<Elem> tree = new ArrayBinSearchTree<Elem>(5);
```

And can be replaced by diamond syntax:

```
AbstractBinSearchTree<Elem> tree = new ArrayBinSearchTree<>(5);
```

Assuming you're using Java 7 or higher

Comment: When i do that i get this error: Bound mismatch: `The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>> of the type AbstractBinSearchTree<E>`

Comment: Ah, right, you also need to modify AbstractBinSearchTree, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you for saving my day! @Jeroen Steenbeeke

Answer (score 0):

Comparable it's interface,then you must to change "extends" to "implement"

Comment: In a generic type declaration, `<E extends Comparable<E>>` is correct syntax.

Comment: @khelwood,Exactly!

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment.